# Graphical layout broken

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Can't add elements from the Palette to the editor, nothing appears on the editor, the palette seems ok. This message appears when opening the main.xml layout file from a newly created project:

```
The project target (Android 2.2) is still loading.
```

The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.

Also, on the error log:

```
    eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/artur/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/artur/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation


Error
Thu Feb 02 12:53:03 CET 2012
Error while loading editor

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$PhoneConfigComparator.compare(ConfigurationComposite.java:1068)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$PhoneConfigComparator.compare(ConfigurationComposite.java:1)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1281)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.selectConfigMatch(ConfigurationComposite.java:1098)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.findAndSetCompatibleConfig(ConfigurationComposite.java:988)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.onXmlModelLoaded(ConfigurationComposite.java:724)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:976)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditor.java:583)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.initUiRootNode(LayoutEditor.java:505)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.xmlModelChanged(LayoutEditor.java:324)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1511)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createTextEditor(AndroidXmlEditor.java:765)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createAndroidPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Help?

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of Eclipse (Indigo/3.7) and ADT?

Comment: No code to post, it even happens on a new layout file. I was using Indigo and latest ADT. I ended up using motodevstudio and it's working for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of reasons why the graphical editor errors and doesn't open, but I fixed my editor by deleting my custom device configurations.

To do this in the graphical editor open the drop down that is related to the device shown in the editor. For example 3.7in WVGA Nexus. **Click the "Add Custom..." option** at the bottom. **Select your custom** setups in the popup **and delete** them. After reopening the graphical editor it worked for me.

Hopefully this helps someone else.